# Assembly plugin generating 2 jars. One with classfiles. One with dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am having trouble building a jar using the assembly plugin. I have a bunch of system jar files that I want bundled alongside class files of the project.

I was looking to do something like:

```
   final
    - lib
      - system.jar
      - system1.jar
    - com
      - servlet
       -- etc
```

I have tried to use the assembly plugin but it generates 2 jars. One with just the lib with my jars and another with the class files.
I have read through the assembly docs but I must be missing something.

Here is the build element I have in my pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>jackson-mapper-asl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.4</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.4-sc1.jar</systemPath>
   </dependency>
   //... etc

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>final-jar</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>single</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                     </descriptors>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
```

This is my assembly file (assembly.xml)

```
<assembly>
   <id>distribution</id>
   <formats>
      <format>jar</format>
   </formats>
   <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
   <dependencySets>
      <dependencySet>
         <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
         <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
         <unpack>false</unpack>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
         <includes />
      </dependencySet>
   </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Any idea how I can merge these jars together?

Comment: Have you tried to `<useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>` ?

Comment: The jar file is the output of the project, the so-called project artifact. It will always be created. The assembly will then be created alongside. So you will always end up with two. Focus on adding the right things in the assembly, such as khmarbaise suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You would usually have a much simpler layout, such as:

```
final
- lib
  -system.jar
  -system1.jar
  -project.jar
```

I.e. the project itself is a jar too, and included in the lib. In this case just add `<useProjectArtifact>true/>useProjectArtifact>` to the `dependencySet`.

If you really, really want to have classes copied in directly, try adding a `fileset` to the assembly, copying from `target/classes` into your root location

```
<fileSets>
 <fileSet>
  <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
  <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
 </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```